# PhpSpreadsheet записать не считывая в память?

Tags: php, память, phpspreadsheet

Использую либу "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.5". Возникает задача сделать большой файл ексель в фоновом процессе (именно на этой либе). Причем объем памяти ограничен. Пробовал устанавливать redis на кэш, тогда работает очень меделнно. Рассматриваю второй вариант, записывать кусками. Однако не могу найти подход, чтобы записать в файл новую порцию данных не считывая старые.

Comment: Формат файла к сожалению такой что записать новые данные не зная старых - проблематично =) Максимум что возможно - минимизировать чтения, но врятли это реализуемо с указанной библиотекой.

Comment: а сделать csv файл, который потом конвернуть в excel не вариант? сложная разметка и т.п.?

Comment: @n.osennij сложная разметка, много стилей, так бы использовали spout